File not received properly in Azure server using SFTP
I am copying a file from my z/OS Unix System Services (USS) server to a Windows server in Azure using SCP. I am able to connect with both SSH and SFTP to the Azure server on port 22 from my USS server, using the below  command:
scp TESTFILE2 azureuser@azureserver:e:\search\integration\products
Returns the below output saying the file is copied:
(USS):USSUSR:/u/ussusr/TEST: >scp TESTFILE2 
azureuser@azureserver:e:\search\integration\products
azureuser@azureserver 's password:

TESTFILE2   100%    2404    2.4KB/s    00:00      
                                                                                                         
(USS):USSUSR:/u/ussusr/TEST: >

However, the file is copied with the name as 'e' with 0 bytes, the last one at 11:02 timestamp.
Connected to azureserver.
sftp> ls -ltr

drwx******    1 -        -               0 Apr 21  2020 CombinedPrimFiles

-rw-******    1 -        -        73321585 Apr 21  2020 TEST1_.TXT

-rw-******    1 -        -            2500 Aug 19  2021 TEST2_1.TXT

-rw-******    1 -        -        73321588 Jun 14 09:30 TEST3_ACPT.TXT

-rw-******    1 -        -               0 Jun 14 11:02 e

I tried various syntaxes of SCP command in different ways, but none of them are working. The SCP command is only taking the 'e' which is the directory name, please can you help me fix this error to copy the file properly.

scp TESTFILE2 azureuser@azureserver:e:\search\integration\products

This is the same command I tried and eventhough its working, in the remote server, its giving 0 bytes of file.

That command is the problem. If that path is passed to Windows, it probably needs to be escaped. Tell us the other syntaxes that you tried.

Usually on Windows, a path that contains a colon is enclosed in double quotes.

I tried these syntaxes


scp TESTFILE2 azureuser@azureserver e:\search\integration\products


scp TESTFILE2 azureuser@azureserver e:/search/integration/products


scp TESTFILE2 azureuser@azureserver:e:/search/integration/products


scp "TESTFILE2" azureuser@azureserver:~e:/search/integration/products


scp TESTFILE2 azureuser@azureserver:/search/integration/prim/products



Finally I tried this also - scp TESTFILE2 azureuser@azureserver:"e:\search\integration\products" but it throws the error "no such file or directory"

That seems closer. There's probably a special blend of magic and dirt to arrive at the required syntax. Does the path exist as a directory? Maybe a trailing backslash?

Yes Greg sir, the path do exists in the remote server.
